# Is there a native oracle capability where apps can hook on to receive updates?

Tags: oracle

I have multiple data sources inserting and updating to an oracle10g database. I also have multiple clients that would like to know when an insert or update has occured. I would like to know if oracle has some kind of native ability for my clients to realize that an insert or update has occured? I feel like the answer is no, but wanted to ask just in case.

Thanks!

edit: ideally push notification

Comment: Push notifications?  Or Polling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different mechanisms depending on your goals.

You can use [Oracle Asynchronous Queues (AQ)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e11013/aq_intro.htm) to publish the changes and then have your applications subscribe to the changes either via OCI or through one of the higher level Oracle AQ APIs (such as having AQ feed a JMS queue for a J2EE application).

If you are writing an OCI application, Oracle provides support for [continuous query notification](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci10new.htm#CJGHFEDD) which is another method of pushing data to the client.

Finally, your applications could use Oracle [Change Data Capture (CDC)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/cdc.htm#DWHSG016) to subscribe to changes.  This last option would be more of a poll option (i.e. your application would ask every few minutes if there had been any interesting changes).  The other two would be push options.

Answer (score 2):

We've used DBMS_ALERT quite successfully; you can use a trigger to send an alert to a client registered to receive notifications. Effectiveness probably depends somewhat on the number and types of changes you're looking for.
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_alert.htm